# Cudafy.NET - CUDA.NET exception ErrorInvalidValue

Tags: c#, .net, cuda, cudafy.net

I am using Cudafy.NET to perform image processing on the GPU. I have set up my class along with the first function (PerformBarrelCorrection running on the CPU) to set up the multiple threads to perform the logic calculation for each pixel in the image.

However every time I launch the function on the GPU it throws an exception:

> An exception of type 'Cudafy.Host.CudafyHostException' occurred in
>   Cudafy.NET.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: CUDA.NET exception: ErrorInvalidValue.

Here is the class in its entirety commented to show the line on which the exception is thrown.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Cudafy;
using Cudafy.Host;
using Cudafy.Translator;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace AForgeTrial
{
    class GPUProcessing
    {
        public CudafyModule km;
        public GPGPU gpu;

        public GPUProcessing() {
            km = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy();
            gpu = CudafyHost.GetDevice(CudafyModes.Target, CudafyModes.DeviceId);
            gpu.LoadModule(km);
        }

        public Bitmap PerformBarrelCorrection(Bitmap source, double strength, float zoom, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
        {
            byte[] bmp = ImageToByteArray2(source);

            int halfWidth = imageWidth / 2;
            int halfHeight = imageHeight / 2;

            double correctionRadius = Math.Sqrt(((imageWidth * imageWidth) + (imageHeight * imageHeight)) / strength);

            byte[] dev_src_bmp = gpu.CopyToDevice(bmp);
            byte[] dst_bmp = new byte[bmp.Length];
            byte[] dev_dst_bmp = gpu.Allocate<byte>(dst_bmp);

            double[] correctPass = new double[1];
            correctPass[0] = correctionRadius;
            double[] dev_correctionRadius = gpu.CopyToDevice<double>(correctPass);

            float[] zoomPass = new float[1];
            zoomPass[0] = zoom;
            float[] dev_zoom = gpu.CopyToDevice<float>(zoomPass);

            int[] halfWidthPass = new int[1];
            halfWidthPass[0] = halfWidth;
            int[] dev_halfWidth = gpu.CopyToDevice<int>(halfWidthPass);

            int[] halfHeightPass = new int[1];
            halfHeightPass[0] = imageHeight;
            int[] dev_halfHeight = gpu.CopyToDevice<int>(halfHeightPass);

            //int blksize = ((bmp.Length / 3) / 128) + 1;

            // EXCEPTION HAPPENS ON THE LINE BELOW
            gpu.Launch((bmp.Length / 3), 1).BarrelCorrectionSingleOperation(dev_src_bmp, dev_dst_bmp, dev_correctionRadius, dev_zoom, dev_halfWidth, dev_halfHeight);

            gpu.CopyFromDevice(dev_dst_bmp, dst_bmp);

            // Convert dst_bmp to Bitmap and return it
            Bitmap result;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(dst_bmp))
            {
                result = new Bitmap(ms);
            }
            return result;
        }

        [Cudafy]
        public static void BarrelCorrectionSingleOperation(GThread thread, byte[] src_bmp, byte[] dst_bmp, double[] correctionRadius, float[] zoom, int[] halfWidth, int[] halfHeight)
        { 
            // Move a single byte from source to destination or fill if required
        }

        public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Bitmap img)
        {
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
        }

        public static byte[] ImageToByteArray2(Bitmap img)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                stream.Close();

                byteArray = stream.ToArray();
            }
            return byteArray;
        }

        public void Close() {
            gpu.FreeAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone know anything about this?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own question for anyone interested although its very niche, my code was full of holes.. This successfully performs real-time lens correction using Cudafy.

```
public void PerformBarrelCorrection(double strength, float zoom)
        {
            CheckIsSet();

            int halfWidth = Width / 2;
            int halfHeight = Height / 2;

            double correctionRadius = Math.Sqrt(((Width * Width) + (Height * Height)) / strength);

            _gpu.Launch(Width, Height).BarrelCorrectionSingleOperation(_gdata.SourceImage, _gdata.ResultImage, correctionRadius, zoom, halfWidth, halfHeight);

        }

        [Cudafy]
        public static void BarrelCorrectionSingleOperation(GThread thread, byte[] src_bmp, byte[] dst_bmp, double correctionRadius, float zoom, int halfWidth, int halfHeight)
        {
            // Move a single byte from source to destination or fill if required
            int x = thread.blockIdx.x;
            int y = thread.threadIdx.x;

            int newX = x - halfWidth;
            int newY = y - halfHeight;

            double distance = Math.Sqrt((newX * newX) + (newY * newY));
            double r = distance / correctionRadius;

            double theta;
            if (r == 0)
            {
                theta = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                theta = Math.Atan(r) / r;
            }

            int sourceX = (int)(halfWidth + theta * newX * zoom);
            int sourceY = (int)(halfHeight + theta * newY * zoom);

            dst_bmp[(y * ((halfWidth * 2) * 4)) + (x * 4)] = src_bmp[(sourceY * ((halfWidth * 2) * 4)) + (sourceX * 4)];
            dst_bmp[(y * (((halfWidth * 2) * 4)) + (x * 4)) + 1] = src_bmp[((sourceY * ((halfWidth * 2) * 4)) + (sourceX * 4)) + 1];
            dst_bmp[(y * (((halfWidth * 2) * 4)) + (x * 4)) + 2] = src_bmp[((sourceY * ((halfWidth * 2) * 4)) + (sourceX * 4)) + 2];
            dst_bmp[(y * (((halfWidth * 2) * 4)) + (x * 4)) + 3] = src_bmp[((sourceY * ((halfWidth * 2) * 4)) + (sourceX * 4)) + 3];
        }
```